# httpcookie response header domain attribute returning "too many re-directs"

Tags: http, iis, header, response, httpcookie

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

I have set in IIS web.conf the following:

httpCookies domain="FQDN" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"

When I try and login to the website with a username that requires its password to be changed, it returns:

This page isn’t working  redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
httpCookies ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

However, if I set in IIS web.conf the folling:

httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"

If login to the website with the username that requires its password to be changed, and it requests I change the password.

Hope someone has seen this behaviour and knowns how to resolve

Thanks!

See above for the troubleshooting steps.

Comment: What is the result of logging into the website with a normal username? Why do you need to log in to a website with a username whose password has expired? Please describe your needs in detail?

Comment: You could try setting the domain property to a more generic domain that includes all subdomains that will use cookies. If your website is hosted at "www.example.com", you can set the domain attribute to ".example.com". This will allow cookies on all subdomains of "example.com".